# How to set Localization / culture in iOS Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How to set Localization / culture of my app in iOS Xamarin?

I know we can get get localized string as mentioned **[here](http://blog.xamarin.com/howto-localize-ios-storyboards-monotouch/)** but I want to keep my phone / device language as it it for e.g. English but when my app loads, I want to change culture from English to Japanese / Spanish.

How can we set culture of app in iOS using Xamarin C#?

Using XCode may be we can set it using below code but now aware with how to set with Xamarin iOS C#

```
[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es-MX"]
```

Comment: I don't know why it seems off-topic? Can't we ask question or resources related to set culture of app for Xamarin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solutions for set localized string in Xamarin

```
var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("en", "lproj");
NSBundle languageBundle = NSBundle.FromPath(path);
lblEn.Text = languageBundle.LocalizedString("Task Details", "Task Details");

var path1 = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("es", "lproj");
NSBundle languageBundle1 = NSBundle.FromPath(path1);
lblEs.Text = languageBundle1.LocalizedString("Task Details", "Task Details");
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image: Here is the folder structure:]

Here is the example localizable.strings file:

[image: Here is the example localizable.strings file:]

Comment: i am getting an error that path is empty

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want to do with the locale but the equivalent of the Objective-C code in Xamarin would be this:

```
var locale = new NSLocale("es-MX");
```

You can also create a new CultureInfo to use in string formatting:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
```

Using the CultureInfo in the app:

```
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fi-FI");

        var datetime = DateTime.Now;

        var date = string.Format(cultureInfo, "{0}", datetime);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(date);
```

Output:

```
    9.8.2014 16:32:10
```

Numeric formatting:

```
        double d = 0.10001;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format
            (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fi-FI"), "Finnish numeric : {0}", d));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format
            (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX"), "Mexican numeric : {0}", d));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format
            (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), "US      numeric : {0}", d));
```

Output:

```
    Finnish numeric : 0,10001
    Mexican numeric : 0.10001
    US      numeric : 0.10001
```

Currency:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format
            (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fi-FI"), "Finnish currency : {0:c}", d));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format
            (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX"), "Mexican currency : {0:c}", d));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format
            (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), "US      currency : {0:c}", d));
```

Output:

```
   Finnish currency : 0,10 €
   Mexican currency : $0.10
   US      currency : $0.10
```

Comment: Thanks @SKall. This will work for the string which I want setup but what about the Text / titles I've set for each controls from the properties? How can I set culture of App so that it automatically refers to its relevant language folder?

Comment: For cross-platform development the most reusable way is to use SQLite databases. Based on the users locale just load up the corresponding db.